# Problem with repeating navigation in my webpage

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

startet with a new project and want to list all contacts of a sqlite database.
I use flask, js and html and jinja2.

My HTML is based on a layout.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
        <title>Buchhaltung - {% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('list_addresses', starting_letter='ALL') }}">Kontakte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url_for('list_invoices') }}">Rechnungen</a></li>
                    <!-- Add links for other menu items -->
                    <!-- ... -->
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
        <div class="content" id="content">
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>

        <footer>
            
        </footer>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

**my address list inherits from this layout.html**

``
`

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

<!--
{% block title %}Address List{% endblock %}
 -->
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h1>Kontakt Liste</h1>
    {% include 'address_filter.html' %}
</div>
<div>
    {% include 'address_result.html' %}
</div>
{% endblock %}`
```

``

**the address_filter.html holds a row of letters from a-z and a checkbox to filter the adress list.**

``

```
<div class="row">   
    <div class="starting-letters-row">
        <button class="all-button" onclick="filterAddressesByStartingLetter('ALL')">ALLE</button>
        {% for letter in starting_letters %}
        
        <button onclick="filterAddressesByStartingLetter('{{ letter }}')">{{ letter }}</button>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="filter-active">
        <label for="filter-active">Show Active only:</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="filter-active" {% if filter_active != 'false' %}checked{% endif %} onchange="filterAddressesByStartingLetter('ALL')">
    </div>
</div>
```

``

**the address_result.html holds the result-table.

the Flask implementation looks like following
**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g, request, send_from_directory
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

app = Flask(__name__)

# Function to get the database connection
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect('data/rechnung.db')
        g.cursor = g.db.cursor()
    return g.db, g.cursor

# Close the database connection at the end of each request
@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if 'db' in g:
        g.db.close()

# Route to render the home page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def addresses_retrieve_startLetter():
    
    db, cursor = get_db()
    # Retrieve unique starting letters for names (active and inactive to define the maximum letter row) 
    cursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT substr(adr_name, 1, 1) FROM adressen ORDER BY substr(adr_name, 1, 1)' )
    starting_letters = [letter[0] for letter in cursor.fetchall()]

    return  starting_letters 

# Route to display addresses for a specific starting letter

@app.route('/addresses/<starting_letter>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def list_addresses(starting_letter):
    db, cursor = get_db()

    #Get the filter_active parameter from the URL
    filter_active = request.args.get('filter_active', type=bool)
    if filter_active == 'true' or filter_active is None:
        filter_active_arg = 1
    else:
        filter_active_arg = 0

    starting_letters = addresses_retrieve_startLetter()

    # Define Headers
    headers = ['Name', 'Vorname', 'Firma', 'Ort', 'eMail', 'Id']

    # Retrieve addresses from the database for the selected starting letter
    # If starting_letter is 'ALL', retrieve all addresses
    if starting_letter.upper() == 'ALL':
        cursor.execute('SELECT adr_name, adr_vorname, adr_firma, adr_ort, adr_email, adr_id FROM adressen WHERE adr_aktiv = ? ORDER BY adr_name', (filter_active_arg,))
    else:
        cursor.execute('SELECT adr_name, adr_vorname, adr_firma, adr_ort, adr_email, adr_id FROM adressen WHERE substr(adr_name, 1, 1) = ? and adr_aktiv =?', (starting_letter,filter_active_arg,))
        
    addresses = cursor.fetchall()
    # app.logger.info(addresses)
    return render_template('list_addresses.html', starting_letters= starting_letters, headers=headers, addresses=addresses, filter_active=filter_active)`
```

When start the server and open my page then the navigation showns once.

Upon clicking on a letter or the checkbox to filter the list then
the naviagtion gets duplicated.

[Result in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA74G.png)

[Debug >> Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJo3p.png)

Comment: GIT COpilot told me the solution.. i replaced the whole page instead only the newly changed data opject

Answer (score 0):

GIT COpilot told me the solution.. i replaced the whole page instead only the newly changed data opject

```
fetch(`/addresses/${startingLetter}?filter_active=${filterActive}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            // Create a temporary div to hold the HTML response
            var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.innerHTML = html;

            // Extract the 'addressList' part from the response
            var newAddressList = tempDiv.querySelector('#addressList');

            // Replace the existing 'addressList' with the new one
            var oldAddressList = document.querySelector('#content #addressList');
            oldAddressList.parentNode.replaceChild(newAddressList, oldAddressList);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).